# not found database name in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have many file check in my codeigniter project but i have not found database name please ans me

```
    $active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = DBHOST;
$db['default']['username'] = DBUSER;
$db['default']['password'] = DBPASS;
$db['default']['database'] = DBNAME;
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: This is the only file where mention database name 

$[defaults][database ]= dbname is your. Database name

Comment: Looks like you have to fill in the database info

Comment: not found database that is big reason

Comment: Where have you defined your database global variables?

Answer (score 1):

normally you would set these equal to an env variable which set the values for each level of production ex `$db['default']['hostname'] = getenv('DB_HOST');`

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';//ex 'localhost'
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';//username of your database
$db['default']['password'] = 'root';//password of your database
$db['default']['database'] = 'databasename';//name of data base
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';//you can leave this as is
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;//you can leave this as is
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;//you can leave this as is
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;//you can leave this as is
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';//you can leave this as is
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';//you can leave this as is
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';//you can leave this as is
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';//you can leave this as is
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;//you can leave this as is
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;//you can leave this as is
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're trying to do here, but a better approach would be to create multiple database groups which has different database settings for them.

```
if(ENVIRONMENT == "production"){
    $active_group = 'production';
} else if(ENVIRONMENT == "development"){
    $active_group = 'default';
}

$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$db['default']['username'] = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$db['default']['password'] = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$db['default']['database'] = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

/* Production config */

$db['production']['hostname'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
$db['production']['username'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
$db['production']['password'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
$db['production']['database'] = 'XXXXXXXXXXX';
$db['production']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['production']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['production']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['production']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['production']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['production']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['production']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['production']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['production']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['production']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['production']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

You will basically set your environment variable in the index.php file and switch between environments from there. That way, you will have your database settings in place and switching becomes easy not only for the database settings, but also for the other configs you have.

Answer (score 0):

**DBNAME** shows it is define as constant, my guess it must be define in **constant.php**

or

You can use **grep** or **notepad++** search in files feature to look for "DBNAME" in whole folder. This way you will get the file where it is define as constant and so the database name you are looking for.

or

If you are interested in only db name then in same config file add below line at the top

```
<?php
die(DBNAME);
```

and hit the any page of the project, it will print the database name.